# Как XML завернуть в таблицы ? (в отдельные таблицы)

Tags: php, html, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
    <book> 
        <title>Heart of a Dog</title>
        <author>Mikhail Bulgakov</author>
        <released>1925</released>
    </book>
    <book> 
        <title>Postmortem</title>
        <author>Patricia Cornwell</author>
        <released>1990</released>
    </book>
    <book> 
        <title>The Sign of the Four</title>
        <author>Arthur Conan Doyle</author>
        <released>1890</released>
    </book>
</books>
```

```
<?php 

$x = simplexml_load_file('books.xml');

foreach($x->book as $book){     
    echo "<p><b>Book title:</b>".$book-> title. "<br />".
    "<b>Author:</b>".$book-> author. "<br />".  
    "<b>Publication date:</b>".$book-> released. "<br />";      
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    $x = simplexml_load_file('books.xml');

    foreach($x->book as $book){     
        echo "<table border=1><tr><td><b>Book title:</b>".$book-> title. "</td>".
        "<td><b>Author:</b>".$book-> author. "</td>".  
        "<td>Publication date:</b>".$book-> released. "</td></tr></table>";      
    }
?>
```